# When I start my laptop and write my password the screen is often only grey

Tags: shutdown, startup, restart

Good evening,
When I start my computer it loads normally and after I have typed my password to get to the desktop I often get only a grey screen. I have to shut down or put the computer to sleep mode and turn on my computer to maybe get the desktop up. My computer does not shutdown normally as well but only when I hold the power button. The screen only turns off but the computer is still running.

Comment: What is the version of the system (`uname -a`, `lsb_release -a`? What is the hardware, and also graphical card? (`sudo lshw -class display`) Use "edit"  to add all relevant detail